# Install 2 farms on same server

Tags: sharepoint-server, server-farm, sharepoint-farm, multiple-farms

I have installed SharePoint 2013. Now, I have to install a new SharePoint 2013 farm on the same server.

Is possible to have 2 SharePoint farms on one server?

- With one SQL server
- With one domain
- With one SQL Instance

Answer (score 9):

You cannot install two SharePoint farms on single windows server. Unless you want to create the couple of VM on servers then you can do.

Yes, you can use single SQL server instance for multiple farms. This solution is not recommended for the production farm

Answer (score 7):

The only way you can do this is through Hyper-V where you create a virtual instance, install Windows Server 2012 and SharePoint Server 2013.

They can use the same database server provided that you give them different database names, but the best option is to install the new SharePoint on a SQL Server instance of its own. Such as `TheOriginalDatabaseServer\INS01`.